# SharePoint Calendar recurring item doesn't exist

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

When I am trying to open an recurring item from SharePoint Calendar its showing "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Web Parts Maintenance Page:

> If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web
>   Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your
>   site administrator.

"

Can you please suggest why its coming and How can I open or delete that one?

Comment: do you have any workflow associated with the calendar.

Comment: No, There is no workflow associated with that.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

http://blog.incworx.com/blog/sharepoint-developer-blog/let-me-tell-you-how-i-conquered-item-does-not-exist-it-may-have-been-deleted-by-another-user

Basically truncate the link to the calendar item entry to remove everything after ID=#.  For example, a link that looks like this:

**http://sharepointfarm/sites/somesite/Lists/SomeCalendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=165**.0.2015-07-17T00:00:00Z

You would truncate to the bolded part.

That should pull it up and you can delete it from there.

Comment: Hi Jaffy, the incworx blog no longer exist. Do you still have the solution?

Comment: Thanks Jaffy.. you save my time...