# JSOM, Calendar Recurring task: "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

Tags: calendar, jsom, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I create calendar recurring tasks with JSOM(SharePoint 2013 on-prem). It works, and I can open this item from "All Events"(not "Calendar") view.

But if opened in "Calendar" view - it gives "item does not exist". If I manually create recurring task - it opens well. But all my programmatically created items give this error:

[image]

What I noted - it works Ok if I copy url link and remove everything after ID=n, for example:

http://url/Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=25*.0.2017-05-18T09:00:00Z* - does not work
http://url/Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=25                        - opens succesfully

Here is code snippet:

```
            var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
            var web = context.get_web();
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Calendar");

            var ici = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var item = list.addItem(ici);

            // set details
            item.set_item("Title", "Bob's birthday");
            item.set_item("fRecurrence", true);
            item.set_item("EventType", 1);
            item.set_item("EventDate", '2017-05-18T09:00:00Z');
            item.set_item("EndDate", '2099-05-18T09:00:00Z');
            item.set_item("RecurrenceData", "<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><yearly yearFrequency='1' month='5' day='18' /></repeat><repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever></rule></recurrence>");

            item.update();

            // execute query
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                console.log("Calendar Birthday item successfully added.");
            }, function(sender, args) {
                console.log("Error in sharepoint jsom: " + args.get_message());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Created workaround for this.

Tried to crteate items using REST but same result. So added script that removes timestamps from Calendar view:

```
jQuery('a[href*="DispForm.aspx"]').each(function () {

    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var urlNoTimestamp = url.slice(0, -23);

    jQuery(this).attr('onclick', 'openDialog("' + urlNoTimestamp + '")');
    jQuery(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
    jQuery(this).removeAttr("target");
});
```

so

> ../Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=20.0.2017-05-17T15:00:00Z

become:

> ../Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=20

Now forms open successfully

See these threads:

- [SharePoint Calendar recurring item doesn't exist](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142028/sharepoint-calendar-recurring-item-doesnt-exist)
- [How to open a calendar item in a modal dialog?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80670/how-to-open-a-calendar-item-in-a-modal-dialog)