# Recurring Event Created by SPD Web Service Call gives error Item does not exist when trying to open in Calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api

I have tried adding the following code (found [[here]](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215859/jsom-calendar-recurring-task-item-does-not-exist-it-may-have-been-deleted-by)) to remove the timestamp from the url after creating the recurring data item from a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow using the Call to Web Services function, but it removes the tabs Events and Calendar from the top of the page and does not remove the time stamp.  My biggest question that I cannot seem to find via Google or logical thinking is why this occurs.  The link when an item is created directly in the calendar is the same format as the link created when an item is posted by REST api. Removing the time stamp doesn't make sense as feasible answer. I am just curious about the logic and not doubting Gennady G. by any means.

```
jQuery('a[href*="DispForm.aspx"]').each(function () {

    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var urlNoTimestamp = url.slice(0, -23);

    jQuery(this).attr('onclick', 'openDialog("' + urlNoTimestamp + '")');
    jQuery(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
    jQuery(this).removeAttr("target");
});
```

so

```
../Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=20.0.2017-05-17T15:00:00Z
```

become:

```
../Lists/Calendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=20
```